# Upload a file over 2.15 GB in R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, httr

I've got a manual process where I'm uploading 5-6 GB file to a web server via curl:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @myfile.csv http://myserver::port/path/to/api
```

This process works fine, but I'd love to automate it using R.  The problem is, I either don't know what I'm doing, or the R libraries for curl don't know how to handle files bigger than ~2GB:

```
library(RCurl)
postForm(
     "http://myserver::port/path/to/api",
      file = fileUpload(
        filename = path.expand("myfile.csv"),
        contentType = "text/csv"
      ),.encoding="utf-8")
```

Yeilds `Error: Internal Server Error`

httr doesn't work either:

```
library(httr)
POST(
      url = "http://myserver:port/path/to/api",
      body = upload_file(
        path =  path.expand("myfile.csv"),
        type = 'text/csv'),
      verbose()
    )
```

Which yields:

```
Response [http://myserver:port/path/to/api]
  Date: 2015-06-30 11:11
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: <unknown>
<EMPTY BODY>
```

httr is a little more informative with the `verbose()` option, telling me:

```
-> POST http://myserver:port/path/to/api
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.35.0 r-curl/0.9 httr/1.0.0
-> Host: http://myserver::port
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: text/csv
-> Content-Length: -2147483648
-> Expect: 100-continue
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<- Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<- Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 11:11:11 GMT
<- Connection: close
<-
```

The `Content-Length: -2147483648` looks suspiciously like a 32 bit integer overflow, so I think this is a bug in httr.  I suspect RCurl is experiencing a similar failure.

I'd really love a minimal wrapper around `curl -X POST --data-binary`, but barring that, what are my options for uploading fairly large files from R?

Comment: I assume you're using the latest version of **httr** which is using the [curl](https://github.com/jeroenooms/curl/tree/master/R) R package. If you can't get it to work using Jeroen's package directly (bypassing httr) it might be faster to create an issue on github.

Comment: @joran Yes I am using httr, which depends on curl.  I made a github issue, but in the meantime I'm curious to know if anyone's every upload a 2.2GB+ file to a web-service from R.  I can't be the first person in history to try to do this...

Comment: In the meantime, you could probably use `system` to invoke curl directly.

Comment: @tonytonov Good idea, I'll try that for now.

Comment: Not that it helps hugely, but you might like to add what OS and version, and what R version you're using.

Comment: http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/academic-and-public-service-programs  Have you tried the RevoScaleR package?

Comment: @costebk08 I don't think RevoScaleR includes a replacement for curl.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen See tonytonov's comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bug is fixed in the dev version of httr/curl:

```
devtools::install_github("jeroenooms/curl")
devtools::install_github("hadley/httr")
```

This is a bug in the [httr](https://github.com/hadley/httr) and [curl](https://github.com/bagder/curl) packages for R.  The bug has been [fixed on GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/httr/commit/c893eda50413835ce451ddb5c1f01d5a44f766ae) as of July 2, 2015, and the change will roll out to CRAN soon.

It is also possible I was calling RCurl incorrectly in the above command, but I could never figure out the correct invocation.

Comment: _If_ you actually copy-pasted the above command, you mistyped **uft-8**, its **utf-8**

Comment: @zerweck Good catch!  I think you can use the `(edit)` button below my post to suggest edits, which I can then review.