# How translate this curl command into a R curl call?

Tags: r, curl

I have this curl command that I can call in bash

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' --data-binary @data/data.csv https://some.url.com/invocations > data/churn_scored.jsonl
```

which posts a CSV file to the API endpoint and I redirect the results into a `.jsonl` file.

I can't find where I can specify a data file to POST to the endpoint like using curl's `@`.

What's the way to achieve the CURL post using R's curl package (or any other package)? The redirection of output I can figure out in another way.

Comment: this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148086/upload-a-file-over-2-15-gb-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very helpful site in converting curl commands to other languages: https://curl.trillworks.com/#r

When plugging in your curl command there I got this.

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = 'text/csv'
)

data = upload_file('data/data.csv')
res <- httr::POST(url = 'https://some.url.com/invocations', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
```

Answer (score 1):

To specific symbol `@`. From `man curl`:

```
--data-binary <data>
  (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever.
  If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a filename.  Data is
  posted in a similar manner as --data-ascii does, except that newlines are preserved
  and conversions are never done.

  If this option is used several times, the ones following the first will append data
  as described in -d, --data.
```

It seems no need to worry about `@`

As it mentioned by @chinsoon12, `httr` is a good nice method to handle request:

- `-X` or `--request` translates to `VERB` function `POST()`, which includes `--data-binary`
- `-H` or `--header` translates to `add_headers()`  but there are special functions for setting content type (see below)

So it looks like:

```
library(httr)
response <- POST(
      url = "https://some.url.com/invocations",
      body = upload_file(
        path =  path.expand("data/data.csv"),
        type = 'text/csv'),
      verbose()
    )
# get response and write to you disk
```