# R: How to save the content of a curl request as ascii text?

Tags: r, curl

As a follow on from: [How translate this curl command into a R curl call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678170/how-translate-this-curl-command-into-a-r-curl-call/56678364#56678364)

I can successful do a curl request but the returned result looks to be in a binary format, but the content should be ASCII. How do I write it out as an ASCII file?

```r
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = 'text/csv'
)

data = upload_file('data/data.csv')
res <- httr::POST(url = 'https://some.url.com/invocations', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
content(res, "text")
```

works and if the output is JSON then

```r
content(res, "parsed")
```

works too.